# Не работают стили yii2

Tags: linux, yii2, apache

поставил yii2 advanced на линуксе, настроил apache на 2 домена: frontend и backend.
и на backend не видит стили, хотя не менял ничего.

backend htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule . index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

backend apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost was.local.backend>
    ServerName was.local.backend
    DocumentRoot /var/www/was.local/backend/web
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/backend-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/backend-access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/was.local/backend/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

на фронтенде все то же самое, помимо того, что вместо backend - frontend.
на самой странице в консоли ошибки `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` на все файлы js, css.

---

помогли настройки .htaccess [отсюда](https://github.com/mickgeek/yii2-advanced-one-domain-config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помогли правильные настройки [.htaccess](https://github.com/mickgeek/yii2-advanced-one-domain-config)